# visual studio does not recognize my dynamic user control class. Sometimes it does sometimes it doesn't

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

Hi I have created a user control which is inside a folder called Controls and the class is a partial class which inherits from Web.UI.UserControl. Now from my page which is one level up I just try to access the method inside the usercontrol and so trying to cast it as the type of user control.

But I get build errors. It just cannot recognize that class. I get Type not defined error. But at times it has recognized the class. Dont know why it does that.

Comment: Please provide details, the control code and the build error.

Comment: ... and also on the way you load the control(LoadControl or per Drag&Drop on the Page). Have you registered your control on the aspx-page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Finally I was able to resolve the issue by converting to web application from a website. Now it works exactly as desired. I think there are problems with visual studio website apps. As far as I have read websites do not have as robust support as web app has. So thankyou all for your comments. Finally the flakiness is gone.